# Bash script which would return the total space occupied by files inside a macOS diectory

Tags: shell-script, osx

Am trying at create a bash script which would return the total space occupied by files inside macOS diectory  `~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# AUTHOR:SWASTI BHUSHAN DEB

    # Platfrom:macOS
    # macOS High Sierra 10.13.
    #Checks the total space occupied by files within a directory


    read -e -p "Enter the full path to the Home Directory : userpath
    var=$(sudo du -ach $userpath/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/|tail -1|awk '{print $1}')
    echo "$var"
    exit
```

The command below when used solo in terminal provides the desired result:

```
`du -ach ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/|tail -1|awk '{print $1}'
25G
```

But when put in the script above with $userpath ,the script encounters error:

```
 du: /Volumes/Macintosh: No such file or directory
du: HD/Users/swastibhushandeb/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/: No such file or directory
0B
```

Am not sure whats wrong in this.Any comments/sugesstions/sample script code are welcome

Comment: This happens because the path to your user's home directory, `/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/` contains a space. The solution to all such issues is to _always_ double quote your variables as explained in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote your variables when using them, otherwise paths with spaces and other special characters will not work:

```
read -e -p "Enter the full path to the Home Directory :" userpath
var=$(sudo du -ach "$userpath/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/" |tail -1|awk '{print $1}')
echo "$var"
exit
```

PS: As you throw away most output from `du` you probably don't need the `-a` option.

Comment: I stil get this :du: /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/swastibhushandeb/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/: No such file or directory
0B

Comment: @swastibhushandeb My bad, fixed in the answer.

Comment: ,Thanks for the advice.I double quoted the variable,but its still the same error.

Comment: @swastibhushandeb did you copy/paste directly from my answer? Also, please read the answer to the question linked on top, it explains the whole thing in much more detail.